# ggplot2, scale background color to x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

So I am trying to create something similar to this picture

[image]

After creating a simple graph like

```
SMV <- c(3, 1, 4)
Acidity <- c(1.6, 1.2, 1.7)
Sake <- data.frame(SMV, Acidity)
plot <- ggplot(Sake, aes(x = SMV, y = Acidity)) + geom_point()
```

Is it possible to scale the background color to the x-axis, and if so, can you also concurrently scale it to the y axis? So you essentially have 4 colors as pictured here using ggplot2?

Comment: I've hacked something similar before. In your case, what's the logic for where the different quadrants intersect? Given the difference in scale between x-axis & y-axis, it doesn't look like either 1-1, or from each corner to the pre-determined nucleus point.

Comment: This is definitely possible, but you'd have to be more specific how you want the colors to blend into each other. There's a million possibilities of how that could be implemented.

Comment: I was thinking something akin to how you can scale_color_continous or scale_x_discrete.  I tried doing some "scale_theme_continous" which didn't work.  I had tried it like this.   
`scale_theme_continuous(name="",
                         breaks = c("'5", "'-5", "'-15"),
                         low = "orange", high = "pink", mid = "green")`  
  
Apologies if unclear or glaringly wrong.  Any sort of scaling/color blending is fine if I can figure out how to change it as necessary.